# Debian 'mount': same command different errors

Tags: debian, networking, mount, cifs

I am trying to mount one of network share to my laptop. I am using following command

```
sudo mount -t cifs //server.name/shared /mnt/myfolder -o user="username"
```

However, I am getting very different errors every time I run this command. See attached picture

```
dex@lina:/$ sudo mount -t cifs //server.name/shared /mnt/share -o user="username"
Password for username@//server.name/shared:  ********
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
dex@lina:/$ sudo mount -t cifs //server.name/shared /mnt/share -o user="username"
Password for username@//server.name/shared:  ********
mount error(115): Operation now in progress
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
dex@lina:/$ sudo mount -t cifs //server.name/shared /mnt/share -o user="username"
Password for username@//server.name/shared:  ********
Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
dex@lina:/$
```

In case someone wants to see screen-shot, can find it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k38GJ.png).

`server.name` is a name of a server and not an IP address. I know this server exists because person next to me running Windows 10 and has that share mapped. However, that person have no idea who and how mapped that drive. We both are on same network.

Can anyone tell me what is going on and how can I fix this? I have also tried with `-o rw` but same errors. I am using Debian 9 (stretch) with `xfce`.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) Copy the text here and apply code formatting: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @muru, I have already added text of the command before screen shot.

Comment: But not the errors, and you're talking about multiple "different errors"

Comment: What does the server report in its logfiles?

Comment: @roaima I don't have access to server. I am just an user trying to access common network share folder.

Comment: You could ask the server administrator?

Comment: @roaima , yes. That will be my last choice. I am just trying to see if I can resolve this myself first.

Comment: @roaima, I am figuring out if it is windows or linux running samba. My guess is it is linux running samba. And `my.network.address` is name and not IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Command works when I used **IP address** instead server name.

```
sudo mount -t cifs //0.0.0.0/shared /mnt/myfolder -o user="username"
```